# Почему аннотация @Size не выводит ошибку?

Tags: java, java-ee, валидация, аннотации, bean-validation

Хочу попрактиковаться с валидацией бинов. Использую аннотацию @Size:

```
@Size(min = 22)
String i;
//...
i = "3";
System.out.println(i);
```

Минимальная длина - 22 символа, я присваиваю значение длиной 1 символ, но почему то никакой ошибки не происходит. Правильно я понимаю, что аннотация должна вывести какую то ошибку?

Comment: как строка может иметь минимальное значение?

Comment: @michael_best минимальную длину символов

Comment: тогда 3, это 1 по вашей логике и ошибки нет

Comment: @michael_best так минимальная длина - 22, а я вставляю 1. Получается, что он меньше минимальной длины(не максимальной).

Comment: Чем делаете валидацию?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Не очень понял, я использую weld

Comment: @Алексей если вы посмотрите вопросы по тегу [tag:bean-validation], то заметите, что многие из них связаны с заблуждением, что достаточно добавить аннотацию и валидация начнёт работать. Это не так, валидацию что-то должно делать. Обычно её делает ORM при сохранении сущностей в базу, в некоторых случаях (не всегда) DI-контейнер, иногда web-фреймворк, если специально настроен, или ваш код с помощью вручную созданного экземпляра [Validator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/Validator.html).

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev спасибо, я понял

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev "Обычно её делает ORM при сохранении сущностей в базу" - это значит, что если я буду использовать какой-нибудь JPA, например hibernate, то мне не надо будет писать собственный валидатор?